# EOL error in timeit setup statement

Tags: python, timeit

I'm encountering the `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` error when running `timeit.Timer`. My setup is a long string spanning multiple lines:

```
setup = """
import datetime
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

ydate = str(20180308)

# Import
path = 'path_to_file'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv'))
all_files = [x for x in all_files if ydate in x]
all_files = [x.replace('\\','/') for x in all_files]"""
```

I've moved quotation marks around, tried swapping around the `'` and `"` locations, anything I could think of that usually fixes this error but it still throws the error when I run

```
t = timeit.Timer("[pd.read_csv(x,encoding='latin-1') for x in all_files]", setup=setup)
t.timeit()
```

Also open to a different way to time this. I'm basically comparing the time for `map` vs a list comprehension solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SyntaxError occurred in the last line of the setup. One solution is to add a pair of backslashes on the last line:

```
setup = """
import datetime
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

ydate = str(20180308)

# Import
path = 'path_to_file'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv'))
all_files = [x for x in all_files if ydate in x]
all_files = [x.replace('\\\\', '/') for x in all_files]"""
```

However, `glob` should return valid paths for your operating system. So if you replace the backslash by the forward slash, your OS might not be able to find the files anymore. In that case, I would recommend skipping the last line of your setup:

```
setup = """
import datetime
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

ydate = str(20180308)

# Import
path = 'path_to_file'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv'))
all_files = [x for x in all_files if ydate in x]"""
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked. Looks like it has kept the backspace in my filenames and given an `OSError` that the file does not exist.

Comment: I would assume that `glob` returns valid paths for your operating system, so if you replace the backslash by the forward slash your OS might not be able to find the files anymore. Have you tried skipping the last line of your setup?

Comment: Removing the last line worked! Thank you. If you want to edit your answer I'll accept as correct.